# Do conditional delegation or different member types break the Composite pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, composition, delegation

Here's how I understand the composite pattern:

In the composite pattern, a root object is composed of objects which may be further composed.  Moreover, to be considered composite, all those objects expose a common interface.

My question appears twice in *italics* below.  An example given by a mentor of mine is a filesystem represented by objects:

```
interface Node {
  public int size();
}

class Folder implements Node {
  List<Node> contents;

  public int size() {
    int size = 0;
    for (Node n : contents)
      size += n.size();

    return size;
  }
}

class File implements Node {
  int size;

  public int size() {
    return size;
  }
}
```

This seems pretty clean.  It has a nice property that I'm wondering about:

- A `size()` call on `Folder` calls `size()` on **all** member `Nodes`s, there is no condition guarding `size()` calls on member `Node`s.  *If there were a condition guarding `size()` calls on children `Node`s, would the structure no longer be Composite pattern?*

To clarify, I'll give another example.  Say a `Person` object can `grab()`, and `Person` is composed of 2 `Hand`s and 1 `Mouth`.  Both `Hand` and `Mouth` can `grab()`.  On an instance of `Person`, calling `person.grab()` will call `grab()` on **one** of its members capable of `grab()`.  For instance, the left `Hand` will `grab()` if the right `Hand` is already full, and both `Hand` will grab if the object is heavy.

*Is that Composite pattern, even though there are conditional guards on member calls?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The composite pattern is a good choice for (recursive) tree-like structures, where the clients want to use operations from the interface without actually knowing if something is a composite or a leaf. In other words, they are expecting the derived classes to confirm to the Liskov substitution principle. What does not matter is how the operations are implemented internally.

So your `Person` example is not a bad choice for the composite pattern because its internal `grab` implementation contains a conditional. It is a bad choice because a `Person` is not a **recursive** tree-like object. It may be composed of hands and mouth, but not of other `Person` objects, and I do not see a good term which would qualify as a common base class for `Person` and `Hand`, or a use case where a client can ignore the fact he is asking a person to grab, or a hand.

Comment: I suppose `Person` and `Hand` could both implement a `Grabber` interface, but that feels like a contrivance to shoehorn self-similarity where it doesn't belong.  Thanks for the answer!